# Is there is a way to install VB.net 2010 express on a Linux Machine?

Tags: linux, vb.net, mono, wine

I am using ubuntu in my PC and i am learning VB.net these days for a project i just want to know that is it possible to program VB.net on a Linux machine ? I tried VB 6 Enterprise edition and more than 90 % of modules are working but i need vb.net and i also tries VB.net 2010 Express but it won't install in wine i also tries Sharp Develop (The Open Source IDE for .NET) and it is also not installing 
Finally i am on MONO but that very rough even i can't drag and drop widgets in a vb form application in mono i have to write codes for everything please clear my doubts

Comment: Forget VB.NET, learn C# instead. Also forget form designers and use something that lets you write forms in markup. The winforms designer sucks.

Comment: VB/C# makes no difference. Learning to convert between them takes a couple of days at most, if you understand either passably well. If you have a background in C-style languages/Basic, it'll be even quicker. (Note: If you _do_ go with VB, make sure `Option Strict` is on. Always. Without it you get a massive performance hit and miss a lot of .Net benefits)

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen write forms in markup means coding right ?

Comment: @TheLinuxGuy: Yes, except any modern markup-based GUI toolkit will make it easier to write your UI in code than mess around with the mouse (most importantly they have layout algorithms, which means you don't need to manually specify pixel positions like it's 1995)

Comment: @Basic It's all about Syntax of a programming language i am from Python Background

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen is it true ? Because in Tkinter to make a GUI i still have to give the co-ordinates of an element ie- buttons and believe me that's the most annoying thing in this entire world

Comment: @TheLinuxGuy: Embrace the braces!

Comment: @TheLinuxGuy: If it forces you to do that it doesn't sound like a very good GUI toolkit. If you want to go .NET look up XAML and WPF!

Comment: Ya i am trying so hard to learn .net Technologies In India there is no value of your Python Skills All they want is .net or Java :(

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Note that Mono [doesn't implement WPF/XAML](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/wpf/) so running it on nix might be an issue.